# Why does "Power off" actually reboot?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, power-on, nexus-5

If I hold my power button, I presented with the option to "Power off" my device. I touch it, and my phone (a LG Nexus 5 running on Android 4.4 KitKat) indeed turns off. However, it suddenly turns back on. If I power off multiple times, it eventually stays off. Is this normal? Does the phone restart if it is aware of pending updates or something?

Comment: No, it's not normal. If you are in warranty, go to the service center. OTA updates aren't triggered automatically. You need to tap it from notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because long pressing the power button on all most any android device(if not all) will reboot the device. It is meant to be the restart button in case on a device something goes wrong, you have the option to hard reset the device.

To correctly shut down a device you have to tap the power button and select the option to power of, or if you are in CWM select "Power off device", or I think you can shut it down using adb to.

Comment: This is likely the issue. I haven't observed the reboot issue the past couple days. If I do, I'll look into replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

"Power Off"(menu selection) actually reboots my Kit Kat if it's plugged into the computer with USB debugging on. If i disconnect, the power off powers off.